# Group By on a single column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In my project I have a requirement where my select query return multiple column but for summation of the amount I have to group by a single column. Details is given below.

Example: This is just a example as my query is very big with multiple joins.

```
    Table -tb1

    ---------------------------

        CASE | Amount | Customer
        ---------------------------
        CS001| 50     | 1
        ---------------------------
        CS003| 100    | 2
        ---------------------------
        CS001 | 2000  | 3

Table -tb2
            ---------------------------
            Customer | Name| Age
            ---------------------------
            1| John | 69
            ---------------------------
            2| Robert| 23
            ---------------------------
            3| Tammy| 23
            ---------------------------
```

Now I would like to fetch all the records by joining these 2 table but with a sum of the **Amount**. So, I would like to group by only though **CASE**

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What result do you expect, based on those two sample tables?

Comment: Just in case this is a homework question, you should be aware of [this](https://imgur.com/a/g15GG). This might not be **your** instructor, but be aware that instructors/professors/etc **do** patrol StackOverflow - and sometimes they give each student a slightly different question, just so they know who's posted their homework. Tricksy little devils, they are...and hopefully this doesn't apply in your case. Best of luck.

Comment: If you want to output the customer, you must also group by customer, otherwise what do you  want to display as customer if you group only by case? E.g. case `CS001` has customers `1` and  `3`.

Comment: you'll use `case` and `amount` columns. Well, why do you need the second table then ?

Comment: Oliver - I would like to group by case|customer name | and amount(Summation).

My problem with my query is when I group by case it's asking the group by should be for all the select columns.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I have used a join with group by. You can use a left or a right join to have more records if exists in either table1 or 2

```
   Select 
    a.[case] -- CASE is a  reservedkeyword
     ,a.customer,sum(amount),
   b.name,b.age from table1 a
     join -- or left join/right join
    table2 b
     on 
       a.customer=b.customer
       group by a.case
```

Comment: All columns in the select list must either occur in the GROUP BY or must be aggregated (SUM, COUNT etc.).

Comment: This is tagged for Oracle. I don't think it's going to like `[case]`.

Comment: In this case this query will not work as I do not want to aggregate function on all the fields rather only on case id

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select tb1.*, tb2.*, sum(amount) over (partition by case) as case_amount
from tb1 join
     tb2
     on tb1.customer = tb2.customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

When grouping, every column appearing the the `SELECT` list must either be part of the `GROUP BY` list or must have an aggregate function applied to it (like COUNT, SUM, MAX etc.).

```
SELECT
    t1."CASE", t2.Customer, t2.Name, t2.Age, SUM(t1.Amount) As TotalAmount
FROM
    tbl1 t1
    INNER JOIN tbl2 t2
        ON t1.Customer = t2.Customer
GROUP BY
    t1."CASE", t2.Customer, t2.Name, t2.Age
```

Since `CASE` is a reserved word in SQL, I escaped it the Oracle way by enclosing it in double quotes.